# spring data JPA ignoring fetchmode on query methods

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have entities that have transitive relationships. So Entity A is mapped OneToMany to entity B and entity B is mapped OneToMany with entity C. 
Entity A has a property, userID, which is NOT the primary key and I need to fetch all records for a user ID from the DB. Due to the requirements, I want to fetch the child records of A and B eagerly. I have annotated the entities with FetchMode join and my Repository has a method findByUserId(int userId).
I am using spring data JPA with hibernate as underlying ORM. 
Executing the above query method fires multiple queries, though I expected only one query with join to be fired.

I have already tried EntityGraphs, annotated my repository method with NamedQuery, tried mapping entities ManyToOne bidirectional but nothing seems to be working.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A_Master")
public class EntityA{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private int userId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_reservationId")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<EntityB> bEntities= new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Entity_B")
public class EntityB{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_journeyId")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<EntityC> cEntities = new ArrayList<>();
}

public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, Integer>
{
    public List<EntityA> findByUserIdAndStatus(String userId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FetchType` defines how the collection is loaded. Is it going to be loaded immediatly or is it going to be loaded lazily (on demand).

In contrast `FetchMode` defines what will be the mechanism that will load the collection. When you have marked your collection with:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

This is a **nonsense** because by default the `fetchType` of OneToMany is lazy, but you can't have JOIN mechanics on a lazy collection. In order to have a JOIN you need to have it set to EAGER.

The default FetchMode in hibernate is SELECT and this is the prefered fetchmode because it is very efficient with respect of cache usage where the access is based on a key. I would recommend you to use `FetchType.Lazy` with `FetchMode.SELECT` and **enabled collection batching**.

Comment: I have used Fetchtype eager with FetchMode join and it is not working. I need this combination since the tables have huge data and I need to fetch all records immediately. No matter what I do, this combination is not working with data JPA query methods. I even annotated my JPARepository method with named query, explicitly writing a SQL join query. Even that is not working.

Comment: @Navdeep You can not have Join Join Join on the third level. Enable the query batching so that you end up with "select from C where id in ......" It is not Join you need here, it is "@Batch" annotation

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that. Just curious to know: If I have a findById method in my repository, then it works. Only a single query is fired. When I have findByAnyOtherColumn, that causes problems.